# Scrapy / Use Scrapy Selenium for the first request-page?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-selenium

i have a running solution using scrapy_selenium for a site with javascript-loading.
As you can see in the code below the the SeleniumRequest is used when yielding the detailPage with parseDetails -

But what can i do when i need the SeleniumRequest allready at my mainpage (and not only the detail-page like below)?

How can i use the SeleniumRequest in that situation?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest

class ZoosSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'zoos'
  allowed_domains = ['www.tripadvisor.co.uk']
  start_urls = [
                "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attractions-g186216-Activities-c53-a_allAttractions.true-United_Kingdom.html"
                ]  
  existList = []  

  def parse(self, response):
    tmpSEC = response.xpath("//section[@data-automation='AppPresentation_SingleFlexCardSection']")
    for elem in tmpSEC:
      link = response.urljoin(elem.xpath(".//a/@href").get())   
      yield SeleniumRequest(
        url=link, 
        wait_time= 10,        
        callback=self.parseDetails)  

  def parseDetails(self, response):
    tmpName = response.xpath("//h1[@data-automation='mainH1']/text()").get()  
    tmpLink = response.xpath("//div[@class='Lvkmj']/a/@href").getall()    
    tmpURL = tmpTelnr = tmpMail = "N/A"

    yield {
      "Name": tmpName,
      "URL": tmpURL,
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use own function `start_requests()` which starts first request(s).

```
class ZoosSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def start_requests(self):
        for link in self.start_urls:
            yield SeleniumRequest(
                url=link, 
                wait_time= 10,        
                callback=self.parse)
```

See first point in doc: [Spider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)

```
The first requests to perform are obtained by calling the start_requests() method  
which (by default) generates Request for the URLs specified in the start_urls 
and the parse method as callback function for the Requests.
```